# Enabling application menu in Classic

Tags: app, menu

How can I add to the Standard User profile the classic app menu/launcher? I'm talking about the dark pill menu in the upper right?

This menu is missing from my user. I've assigned the sample console to the user.

[image: Image from https://www.packtpub.com/sites/default/files/Article-Images/3067_03_03.png]

Comment: What do you exactly mean by adding the profile to the menu? Can you add more detail, please? or any mock screenshots if you have one?

Comment: @Mahmood added screenshot.

Comment: Do you want to add the current user profile in the app menu or the `standard user` profile?

Comment: either or. standard user profile would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an app, Goto setup > Apps > New

And then add the **Profile** and **Profile Overview** to add the required profile view in your app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable App Launcher for standard user you need to give Adminstrative Permission "Use Identity Feature" using permission set.
[image]

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Kiran Machhewar